# should i always try to avoid grok parse errors?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a field in my logs that I match for as an IP address like this:

```
grok {
  match => [ "field1", "(?:(?<field2>%{IP})|(%{IP}),\+)"]
}
```

Sometimes this field1 is blank so field2 never gets created in the doc.

This is good because I don't want this field to be added unless it is a valid IP address.

But when this happens the doc is tagged with `_grokparsefailure`. Is this bad? Does this mean I'm doing something wrong and I should avoid _grokparsefailures.

Comment: Can you post some sample values of field1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `_grokparsefailure` is, is a breadcrumb for the maintainer signifying some grok rules may need updating. Performance-wise, it has no meaning for a rule as short as that one. If you really don't care about misses on a grok statement, you can tell it to tag it some other way (`tag_on_failure => ["something"]`).